# Regexp: only capturing a stuff within parenthesis

Tags: javascript, regex

In JavaScript, I want to capture a stuff like `%{VAR}`.
The code below:

```
"I am %{name} and I am %{age}".match(/%\{(.+?)\}/g);
```

Gives me:

```
["%{name}", "%{age}"]
```

Meanwhile I suppose:

```
["name", "age"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `RegExp#exec` and call it in a loop. `String#match()` loses all capturing groups.

```js
var re = /%{([^{}]+)}/g; 
var str = 'I am %{name} and I am %{age}';
var m, arr = [];
 
while ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
   arr.push(m[1]);
}
document.body.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(arr, 0, 4);
```

Besides, you can use an improved regex: `%{([^{}]+)}`.

In JS, you do not have to escape `{` and `}`. Also, to make it more efficient, you can use a **negated character class** `[^{}]` that matches *any character but `{` or `}`*.

**Regex explanation:**

- `%{` - match literal `%{`
- `([^{}]+)` - Group 1: matches 1 or more character other than `{` and `}`
- `}` - a literal `}`.

Comment: Lazy matching `(.+?)` pattern is really an unefficient subpattern, you should avoid using them (with `.*?`) if you can do what you need with just a negated character class.

Comment: `[^{}]*` is not the same as `.+?`. The first is zero or more matches, not `{` or `}`. While the second is one or more not `}`

Comment: @dev-null: Sure, but in the current context it is ok, I agree we can use `+` instead of `*`. The value between `%{` and `}` are unlikely to have `{` or `}`. The `{.+?}` regex actually means *match `{` then any characters but a newline up to the first `}`*.